# I'm getting errors when I try to create a new xml file in eclipse

Tags: xml

I'm trying to create an attrs.xml file under res\values (so I can add AdMob ads).  I right click values, select new, other, XML File, next, give it the name attrs.xml and the file is created, but there are 2 red x marks in the margin.  If I hold my cursor over the x's, the top one (beside the line ) says Premature end of file, and the x right under that line (which is just a blank line) says errro: Error parsing XML: no element found.

Any idea why this is happening?  I have shut down and restarted Eclipse, repeated the process and gotten the same results.

Answer (score 0):

An empty xml file will always give you that error.

You need to fill the xml file with some android UI elements, like so -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </LinearLayout>
```

Once you fill the xml file, rebuild the project the errors should go away..